# Exercise 1.2.4 and Example 4.3.6 in Liu

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

I want to prove that if $X$ is a noetherian scheme then any flat closed immersion into $X$ is open, that is, if $A$ is noetherian then $\varphi:\operatorname{Spec}(A/I)\to\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is open. For that I need the following equivalence:

i) $A/I$ flat over $A$

ii) $I^2=I$

iii) there exist $e\in A$ with $e^2=e$ and $I=(e)$

Then I proved that this induce that $A=(e)\oplus(1-e)$ and finally I conclude that $V(e)=D(1-e)$ which proves that $\varphi$ is open (right?).

So my problems are

ii) $\Rightarrow$ iii) I think there is something with Nakayama lemma because there is $I^2=I$ but how use it... I don't see.

iii) $\Rightarrow$ i) Which criterion to use? Maybe $A/I=JA/I$ for all ideals $J\subseteq A$, but what link with $I=(e)$?

But maybe we make another chain of implications?

Comment: 1. Apply Nakayama's Lemma to the $A$-module $I$.

Comment: Yes, my fault was to only think about NAK with $I$ include in Jacobson ideal...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)  Use [the following isomorphism](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48694/how-to-calculate-torr-i-r-j) $$\operatorname{Tor}_1(A/I,A/J)\simeq (I\cap J)/IJ.$$ Since $A/I$ is $A$-flat you have $\operatorname{Tor}_1(A/I,A/I)=0$, that is, $I/I^2=0$.

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii) $I=I^2$ and $I$ finitely generated implies $I=eA$ with $e=e^2$: from NAK there exists $e\in I$ such that $(1-e)I=0$, so $(1-e)e=0$. Let $a\in I$. Then $(1-e)a=0$, so $a=ea\in eA$. This shows that $I=eA$.

(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) Let $J=(1-e)A$. Then $I\oplus J=A$ and thus $I,J$ are projective $A$-modules. Since $A/I\simeq J$ we get the conclusion.

Comment: The proof of (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) is very neat: bravo, +1. And I strongly encourage you to sign with your real name or at least adopt a more memorable username...

Comment: More elementary, for i)$\Rightarrow$ii) I found $I\hookrightarrow A$ so $I/I^2=I\otimes A/I\hookrightarrow A/I$ with image $0$ so $I/I^2=0$. I found after iii)$\Rightarrow$i) taking $f:M\hookrightarrow N$ and taking $y=ex\in IN$ and $z\in M$ with $f(z)=y=ex$ then $f(ez)=e^2x=ex=y$ so $f(z-ez)=0$ so $z-ez=0$ so $z=ez\in IM$ so $M/IM\hookrightarrow N/IN$ ie $M\otimes A/I\hookrightarrow N\otimes A/I$ so $A/I$ flat. Thanks